# Возможно ли как-то закрыть функцию полностью, или сделать return для неё через другую функцию, которая в неё вложена

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что в одностраничном приложении использую разные функции и в зависиомти от ситуации запускаю их. В функциях находятся запросы на сервер через *socket.io*. Запускать разные функции надо так-как html документа меняется. Цепочка страниц получается такая - создание анкеты > активные пользователи > чат с одним из них.
Вот проблема случилась, когда я добавил, чтобы с чата можно было перейти на страницу к активным пользователям получается я опять запускаю функцию, которая отвечает за эту страницу. И проблема в том, что у меня уже работает как бы сразу 2 одинаковые функции. То есть первая как только я сделал анкету и та которая включилась после того, как я перешел с чата. И начинает по socket.io приходить уже 2 запроса. Звучит странно вообщем я хотел бы только узнать можно ли как-то выключить функцию предположительно вызовом return, но это надо сделать только когда приходит определенный запрос с сервера по socket.io. Выглядит функция в уменшенном варианте так:

```js
function startActiveUsers(){
//Другие действия...


//Запрос при каком меняем функцию и html
socket.on('сonfirmationToChat', function(confirmID, requestID, html) {
    if(ID == confirmID || ID == requestID){
        toAnyPage('chat', 'startChatScript');
    };
});
}
```

Можно ли как то при получении вот этого запроса сделать return функции *startActiveUsers()*? Спасибо

Comment: а вы не думали об использовании какого-нибудь фреймворка?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman,  думал, но вже всё так построил ещё давно и работает(за исключением этого инцидента).

Comment: а почему при выходе со страницы эта функция не "выключается"?

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n, выхода нет, просто содержимое body меняется

Comment: @Horchynskyi, а до этого при переходе от страницы к странице предыдущая функция продолжала работать? Может в самих этих функциях производить проверку на предмет, нужна ли она сейчас или нет и выходить из неё?

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n единственное что я пока придумал, это при получении данных проверяю их на уже существуюущие) если они есть то удаляю. ну там проблема вот только когда человек отсылает заявку на чат. Если ты был в чате и вернулся к активным начинает приходить по 2 заявки если ещё раз зашел и вышел уже по 3) кароче всёреавно это надо переносить на норм фреймворк а пока пусть с проверкой будет)